# IE Automation with SendMessage

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, sendmessage

I'm developing an Automation Software for the IE. 
I tried the SHDocvw, but it worked poorly, because of the busy state of the IE.

Now i wanted to use the Windows SendMessage.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

private const Int32 WM_VSCROLL = 0x0115;
private const Int32 SB_PAGEDOWN = 0x1;

String procName = "iexplore";
var proc = Process.GetProcessesByName(procName)[0];
SendMessage(proc.MainWindowHandle,WM_VSCROLL, (IntPtr)SB_PAGEDOWN, IntPtr.Zero);
```

I want simply scroll in an IE tab. 
I can't find the solution why this isn't working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This fails because you are sending the WM_VSCROLL message to the main window. You need to send the message to child control, which is the window with the scrollbar.

You can enumerate child windows using [EnumChildWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Also you are using "iexplore" Process to get the MainWindowHandle which may not work as there can be several Internet Explorer process running. Try using [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the main window handle.